# Using dynamic templates in meteor

Tags: templates, meteor, dynamic

I'm really stuck trying to use dynamic templates in meteor, and applying filters to the data which populates them. I'd be really grateful for some help.

To give a simple example, I'd like to be able to input tasks into a to do list, with a tag, for whether it is a big or a little task. Then I'd like to be able to display a table of big tasks, and a table of little tasks, separately.

Here are some code extracts, adapted from the official meteor blaze tutorial, so you can see in a general sense what I'm trying to do.

body.html extract

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>

        <form class="new-task">
          <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
          <input type="text" name="taskType" placeholder="Big/little" />
          <button type = "submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    </header>
    <h1>big tasks</h1>
    <ul>
      {{> Template.dynamic template="task" data=bigTasks}}
    </ul>
    <h1>little tasks</h1>
    <ul>
      {{> Template.dynamic template="task" data=littleTasks}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

task.html extract

```
 <template name="task">
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />

    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

task.js extract

```
Template.task.helpers({
  bigTasks() {
    return Tasks.find({}, { taskType: Big, sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  },
});

Template.task.helpers({
  littleTasks() {
    return Tasks.find({}, { taskType: Little, sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  },
});
```

I realise this is perhaps a little more a request for a tutorial, than a specific question, but would be grateful for anything which you can offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous issues with your code.

First, you're using `Template.dynamic` wrong way. It's supposed to include template which name is *dynamic*.

Second, using `Template.dynamic` you're using `data=<helper name>`. That's correct form, but you're using it in `Template.body`, so these helpers also should be in `Template.body`, not in `Template.task`.

And, third issue is that you forgot to wrap your `task` template content in `{{#each}}...{{/each}}`.

As your question is about using `Template.dynamic`, here is how it should be (though there is an another, better way to implement this):

```
Template.body.helpers({
  bigTasks() {
    const tasks = Tasks.find({}, { taskType: Big, sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch();
    return { tasks };
  },
  littleTasks() {
    const tasks = Tasks.find({}, { taskType: Little, sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch();
    return { tasks };
  },
});
```

**`task.html`**:

```
<template name="task">
  {{#each tasks}}
    <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
      <button class="delete">&times;</button>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
      <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Styx - thanks so much. With a few changes to the syntax of the helper function (detailed separately) I was able to get this to work. Really appreciate your help, and all the best!

Comment: @Mark Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering the same challenges, Styx's answer above works, but I found that I needed to also make a few changes to the syntax of the helper function:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  bigTasks() {
    // Show newest tasks at the top
    const tasks = Tasks.find({taskType: "Big"}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch();
  return { tasks };
  },
  littleTasks() {
    // Show newest tasks at the top
    const tasks = Tasks.find({taskType: "Little"}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch();
  return { tasks };
  },
});
```

Styx - thanks so much. I really appreciate you taking the time to help this newbie find my way. All the best!